# Join is Multiplying Table Records

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables and I am trying to join them to get a total count of lines after the creation date in one of the tables. Autokey is my unique identifier in both tables and I also have a group by (hoping this would eliminate the duplicates) but for some reason it is multiplying the results of each table result.

```
select 
  a.autokey,
  a.createdate
  count(*),
  sum (case when a.createdate > b.actualduedate then 1 else 0 end) as incomingLn
from  workflow a 
join auto b on a.autokey = b.autokey  
group by  autokey
```

Comment: update your question and add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I see in your query is that you are counting everythig from nothing...

You have to do a `COUNT(a.*)` or `COUNT(b.*)`, yes ?

Something like this: (As an exaple I will add the `COUNT(a.*)`)

```
SELECT 
  a.autokey,
  a.createdate,
  COUNT(a.*),
  SUM (CASE WHEN a.createdate > b.actualduedate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS incomingLn
FROM  workflow a 
INNER JOIN auto b ON a.autokey = b.autokey  
GROUP BY autokey
```

As a personal recomendation I suggest you to use the `INNER JOIN`, even if you only write `JOIN`, Mysql will understand that you want to use `INNER JOIN`, but for just good practices I added the `INNER JOIN`.